# "Central de ajuda" no site - Referência ao e-mail

Tags: javascript, html, css

Fala, pessoal.

Eu criei um formulário e gostaria de que sempre que uma pessoa reportasse um erro e reclamasse na central de ajuda do site (página na qual o usuário preenche um input/campo e envia seu relato), o botão, assim que clicado, enviasse o que foi digitado para meu e-mail.

Como posso fazer que a mensagem digitada pela pessoa caia no meu e-mail?

Comment: Poste seu código e isole os problemas que vc esta enfrentando e também as dificuldades na pergunta. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender mais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte código:

```html
<form action="mailto:seu@email.com.br" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
  <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

caso queria algo mais controlável a personalizável terá de usar uma linguagem backend (php,java,c#, etc).

espero que tenha ajudado.